# Apply part of kubernetes manifest yaml using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubectl

consider the following kubernetes manifest (mymanifest.yml) :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: firstpod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secondpod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
```

If I do `kubectl apply -f mymanifest.yml` both pods are deployed.
I remember someone told me that it is possible to deploy only one pod. Something like :

```
kubectl apply -f mymanifest.yml secondpod
```

But it doesn't work.
Is there a way to do it?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add labels to the pods

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: firstpod
  labels:
    app: firstpod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secondpod
  labels:
    app: secondpod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
```

Use specific label to filter while applying the yaml. The filter supports `=`, `==`, and `!=`

```
kubectl apply -f mymanifest.yml -l app=secondpod
```

You can also use `--prune` which is an alpha feature.

```
# Apply the configuration in manifest.yaml that matches label app=secondpod and delete all the other resources that are
not in the file and match label app=secondpod.
kubectl apply --prune -f mymanifest.yml -l app=secondpod
```